# Compiling error Runaway argument

Tags: errors

Here is an error I get when compiling

```
Processing: ./myaclatex.tex

Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class

Runaway argument?

./myaclatex.tex:47: Paragraph ended before \href@split was complete.
```

the tex-document can be found here http://f.cl.ly/items/0L2F2o2a21040T0N242t/latex_error_130625.txt

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It looks like you're missing a comma after the `colorlinks=true` directive in the `\hypersetup` instruction.

Answer (score 5):

The problem in your file (the source of the error) is that you used the `\href` command with a single argument, while it takes two.

You wrote (line 46):

```
\href{http://www.personal.ceu.hu/tex/toc.htm}
```

while you have to write something like:

```
\href{http://www.personal.ceu.hu/tex/toc.htm}{description}
```

You also forgot a comma in the `\hypersetup` command after `colorlinks=true`, as pointed out by Mico, but this is only the source of a warning.

Moreover, the lines 38

```
se \href{http://www.personal.ceu.hu/tex/environ.htm} den här läsvärd. tex tabbing
```

and 271

```
han ger många fler exempel på \href{http://www.personal.ceu.hu/tex/counters.htm} men -1 är den viktigaste för mig. då börjar man på 0 i stället för 1.
```

lack the second argument for `\href` but do not produce an error since `\href` is followed by some text (the first character after `\href` is taken as a hyperlink).

Nevertheless, if you want them to work, you have to correct them, as well.

---

Remember that you can use the command `\url` instead of `\href` which takes a single argument and uses the link itself as a hyperlink, if this is what you wanted to achieve.

Note, however that using `\url` the hyperlink will be shown using a mono-spaced font.

Comment: In this context, the `\url` macro can be useful to replace `\href`.

Comment: @PaulGaborit You are right. Just in case the OP is not aware of that command, I'll add in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is the corrected part (lines 35--46)

```
\subsection{environments} % (fold)
\label{sub:environments}

se \href{http://www.personal.ceu.hu/tex/environ.htm}{???} den här läsvärd. tex tabbing

\begin{tabbing}
 text \= more text \= still more text \= last text \\
 second row \>  \> more \\
 . . .
\end{tabbing}

och münga andra nyttiga saker, tex \href{http://www.personal.ceu.hu/tex/toc.htm}{???}
```

`???`'s should be replaced by a proper text.